# Passing jacobian to scipy.optimize.fsolve, when optimising a univariate function

Tags: python, scipy

```
import math  
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def sigma(s, Bpu):  
    return  s - math.sin(s) - math.pi * Bpu

def jac_sigma(s):
    return 1 - math.cos(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bpu = 0.5
    sig_r = fsolve(sigma, x0=[math.pi], args=(Bpu), fprime=jac_sigma)
```

Running the above script throws the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RP12808\Desktop\_test_fsolve.py", line 12, in <module>
    sig_r = fsolve(sigma, x0=[math.pi], args=(Bpu), fprime=jac_sigma)
  File "C:\Users\RP12808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 146, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Users\RP12808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 226, in _root_hybr
    _check_func('fsolve', 'fprime', Dfun, x0, args, n, (n, n))
  File "C:\Users\RP12808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
TypeError: jac_sigma() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am unsure how to pass jacobian to fsolve function... how do solve this?

Thanks in advance..RP

Comment: I think the solver passes the same additional arguments to the Jacobian as to f. Try adding a dummy argument to your Jac.

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks but no joy, it throws minpack error

Comment: I think you should update your Q accordingly, so people can get clues as to what's going on.

Comment: FYI: Parenthese around a single item, `(Bpu)`, have no effect.  You could just as well write `args=Bpu`.  If you want the argument to be a tuple that contains the single item `Bpu`, use `args=(Bpu,)`.  In this problem, `Bpu` is a scalar, so either will work, but if parameter was itself a sequence, it would be necessary to use the tuple form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function that computes the Jacobian matrix must take the same arguments as the function to be solved, and it must return an array:

```
def jac_sigma(s, Bpu):
    return np.array([1 - math.cos(s)])
```

In general, the Jacobian matrix is a two-dimensional array, but
when the variable is a scalar (as it is here) and the Jacobian "matrix" is 1x1, the code accepts a one- or two-dimensional value.  (It might be nice if it also accepted a scalar in this case, but it doesn't.)

Actually, it is sufficient that the return value be "array-like"; e.g. a list is also acceptable:

```
def jac_sigma(s, Bpu):
    return [1 - math.cos(s)]
```